# How to identify Plaid transactions if transaction ID's change

Tags: javascript, python, api, banking, plaid

I noticed that the same transaction had a different transaction ID the second time I pulled it. Why is this the case? Is it because pending transactions have different transaction IDs than those same transactions once posted? Does anyone have recommendations for how I can identify unique transactions if the trx IDs are in fact changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the transaction ID often does change. When a transaction is posted (stops pending), the original transaction ID becomes the pending transaction ID, and a new transaction ID is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The `transaction_id` of a transaction will change when a pending transaction is converted to a posted transaction. When this happens `pending_transaction_id` field of the posted transaction can be used to match it with the original pending transaction.

For more details see this Plaid support article: https://support.plaid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008271814-Pending-transaction-overview